# Why Qt application does not give me exception or error?

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I am new in Qt application with C++. I was checking the crash reports where I created an exception in Qt application but it bypassed the statement and executes successfully.

I was generating the error like:

```
int *ptr;
delete ptr;
delete ptr;
```

but it didn't produce any error or exception.

Can any one tell me what is reason behind this?

Comment: Its possible `ptr` contains `0`.

Comment: A program is not required to do anything in particular when you execute that, as it is undefined.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Answer (score 5):

C++ follows the principle "you don't pay for what you didn't ask for." This means that where languages such as Java and C# do a lot of runtime checks and throw well-defined exceptions when something goes wrong, C++ does not do that. In many cases, it simply says "if you do something illegal, the program's behaviour will be undefined," and leave it at that. Undefined Behaviour means literally anything is allowed to happen—the program is allowed to crash, appear to work, order pizza online.

Deleting an uninitialised pointer or something which wasn't allocated by `new` is precisely one such Undefined Behaviour-inducing operation. Not giving you an explicit error is perfectly withing the program's rights in this case. Your heap is likely to be corrupted beyond repair, though.

Also, in your particular case, there is *one* condition when the code would actually be well-defined—if the value of `ptr` is null. It's perfectly valid to use `delete` on a null pointer, and the result is a no-op. Such initialisation happens automatically for global variables, and *some* compilers do it for local variables as well *in debug builds.*

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an uninitialized pointer is just undefined behavior, so it's not required to give you any error messages - in fact it would be allowed to order you pizza instead.
Although I am surprised that the compiler doesn't produce a warning at least.  This should be easy to diagnose.